# Structure of the semidirect product decomposition

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm looking at a complicated group that involves many semidirect products, and I realized that I have a fundamental confusion about how to use the structure of a semidirect product decomposition of a group.

For example, I know that $S_4$ is the semi direct product of $A_4$ and $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, where $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is generated by a transposition, but I'm unsure about how to use that decomposition to determine an element of $S_4$.  I have two specific questions:

1. Given an element in the semidirect product decomposition, how do I get an element of the group that is not written in the decomposition?   For example, I have an element $((1 2 3 ),(1 2))\in A_4\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\simeq S_4$; what element of $S_4$ is that?  Do I simply conjugate $(123)$ by $(12)$?
2. Using the output of each piece of the decomposition, how do I obtain a single output for the element.  That is, if I again look at $((1 2 3 ),(1 2))\in S_4$, and I look at what that element does to, say, 1, I get $((1 2 3),(12))(1)=(2,2)$.  But since this is an element of $S_4$, I should only get one number as the output, so how do I go about transforming $(2,2)$ into a single output?

Any explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: ad 1) Try multiplication (if $G = N\rtimes H$ then you can write each element $g\in G$ uniquely as product $g = nh$ with $n\in N$ and $h\in H$.) ad 2) look at 1) again. Does this give you an idea?

Comment: Oh, I see: to compute $[(123),(12)](1)$, I actually compute $(123)[(12)(1)]$; I don't evaluate each one individually and then combine their results.  Is that right?

Comment: One has always to worry a bit about the order of both elements (there are different conventions), but otherwise it is as easy as you think.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you so much!